# Extracting all CSS in a single file in Nextjs using mini-css-extract-plugin

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, frontend, mini-css-extract-plugin

I'm using Nextjs and for style, Sass is used. In production mode, I see a lot of css files that are loaded in a sequential manner. I want to load just one css. After some search, I find MiniCssExtractPlugin that can be useful and use in next.config.js. I don't know how to use it. can anyone help me?

```js
const withPlugins = require("next-compose-plugins");
const nextTranslate = require("next-translate");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const withPWA = require("next-pwa");
const withBundleAnalyzer = require("@next/bundle-analyzer")({
  enabled: process.env.ANALYZE === "true",
});

// next.js configuration
const nextConfig = {
  images: {
    domains: ['ibexcdn.com'],
  },
};

module.exports = withPlugins(
  [
    [
      nextTranslate,
      {
        webpack: (config, { isServer, webpack }) => {
          return config;
        },
      },
    ],
    withBundleAnalyzer,

    [
      withPWA,
      {
        pwa: {
          disable: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development",
          dest: 'public',
          runtimeCaching: [
            {
              urlPattern: /.(?:eot|otf|ttc|ttf|woff|woff2|font.css)$/i,
              handler: 'NetworkFirst',
              options: {
                cacheName: 'static-font-assets',
                expiration: {
                  maxEntries: 4,
                  maxAgeSeconds: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 // 7 days
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        },

      },
    ],
  ],
  nextConfig,
);
```

in the documentation of mini-css-extract-plugin, use these codes

```js
module.exports = {
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        styles: {
          name: "styles",
          type: "css/mini-extract",
          chunks: "all",
          enforce: true,
        },
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "[name].css",
    }),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

but I don't know how to add these codes in my next.config.js file

Answer (score 2):

```
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  webpack: (config) => {
    config.optimization = {
      ...config.optimization,
      splitChunks: {
        cacheGroups: {
          styles: {
            name: "styles",
            type: "css/mini-extract",
            chunks: "all",
            enforce: true,
          },
        },
      },
    };
    config.plugins.push(
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: "static/css/[name].[contenthash].css",
      })
    );
    config.module.rules.push({
      // test: /\.css$/,
      // use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader"],
      test: /\.(scss|less|sass|css)$/,
      use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
    });
    return config;
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

Please try above code. it works for me

Comment: It's important to not just post code, but to also include a description of what the code does and why you are suggesting it. This helps others understand the context and purpose of the code, and makes it more useful for others who may be reading the question or answer.

Answer (score 1):

@Anapuram's answer is exactly correct.

Next -as you can imagine- ships with a custom webpack configuration. You can modify this custom webpack configuration in Next's config file: `next.config.js`.

You can take a look at the [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/custom-webpack-config).

In particular the `webpack` property gives you a function with a `config` object you can modify. Make sure not to nuke the existing fields: use `push` and the [`...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) operator instead of direct assignment.

The biggest adjustment you have to make will be to change the `filename` to find the css files in Next's build directory: `filename: "static/css/[name].[contenthash].css"`.